# Django: How to list all Database entries in a form with each having a dropdown field

Tags: python, django-forms, django-views

Django: How to list all Database entries in a form(similar to admin list index page) with each having a dropdown field(review) that can be changed.The dropdown(review field) reads from the database stored value.
When the dropdown value is changed is automatically saved to that entry. I'm Not able to generate the views.py and the form correctly

```
    REVIEW_CHOICES = (
    ('Not-Rev', 'Not Reviewed'),
    ('Rev-NA', 'Reviewed ­ Accepted')
)

  `class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=False)
    review = models.CharField(max_length =30, default=REVIEW_CHOICES[0], choices=REVIEW_CHOICES)`

    class ReviewForm(forms.Form):
    review = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=articles.objects.all(), to_field_name = 'review', required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = articles
        fields = [
            'title', 'review'
        ]
```

Comment: review is the field in the dropdown field

Comment: Your code snippet is broken. Please re-paste it and indent 4 spaces to mark it as code.